# Can White Walkers reanimate the dead in cemeteries?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Since the Army of dead breached the wall and is marching south, I've been thinking. Could White Walkers reanimate corpses/skeletons buried in cemeteries? This would increase numbers of wights immensely, especially when they enter southern parts of the realm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would appear so (at least in the show). The wights that attacked and killed Jojen Reed appeared to come from graves:

It is not yet confirmed that Jojen is dead in the books, but it is heavily implied.

It is also highly speculated that we will see Stark dead rising from the Crypts of Winterfell.

From our first contact with the Wildlings, it is stressed that dead bodies should be *burned*, not buried.

Comment: You mean that opening scene from the S08 trailer?

Comment: You mean the Stark dead rising? Of that, I just mean internet fan speculation. I take the fact that the swords that the statues hold (in the books) have rusted away to nothingness as ominous in that regard. The armed statues symbolize the guarding of the contents of the crypts. Winterfell does not need to be guarded from grave-robbers.

Comment: Dead Ned (Stark) will rise again? Oh my!

Comment: @Rebel-Scum I am not sure the Ned Stark is buried in the crypts of Winterfell. :)

Comment: @byk7 If I remember, at least in the books they got his body back.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum They got his body back in the show too.

Comment: Aah, ok then. :)

Comment: The Walking Starks: Ned Stark (Sean Bean) roams the streets of Winterfell and terrorizes its inhabitants. I'd watch that show!

Comment: Didn't Starks burned their deads?

Answer (score 6):

It would likely depend on the state of decomposition of the bodies. While we have seen some very skeletal looking wights, they still have some form of tissue holding them together.

If burning a body works to save you from being reanimated I think a body that is just bones will remain that way. A standard fire isn't going to destroy bones.

**Update: [I was wrong.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211147/57310)**

Answer (score 5):

In S08E03 we have 100% confirmation.

> in 0:45 we can see the NK resurrecting corpses around, in 3:00 we can see wights in the crypt.

OP: "especially when they enter southern parts of the realm"

> well, thats not gonna happen...

Comment: The video still doesn't give much away and it breaks the spoiler markdown so no need to hide it